# jboss server not deploying webapp artifact

Tags: intellij-idea, web-applications, jboss

I have started the jboss server by copying the war to deploy folder in jboss. But it was throwing the error as the artifact not deployed.  Is there any particular configuration to be followed to make the artifact deployed.

> 09:25:00,894 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile:
>   Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS)

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfszip:
<>../webapp-war-1.14.0-SNAPSHOT.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: Failed to resolve schema nsURI=http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee location=http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd
```

Comment: How does your web.xml look like?

Comment: And which JBoss version?

Comment: version i was trying Jboss 6. Now I had to change that to wildfly 8. Now am facing a different issue..it will be helpful if you have suggestion for that.                                Here is the error log:     ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.<name>-webapp-war-1.14.0-SNAPSHOT.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.<name>-webapp-war-1.14.0-SNAPSHOT.war".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.

Comment: Usually you can find the reason for the failed deployment logged earlier in the log. In this case it seems you have a problem with your build, because it refers "<name>-webapp...." Looks like variable "name" is not resolved during building of the artefact?